# Dynamically change ThinkingSphinx max_matches / offset

Tags: sphinx, thinking-sphinx

Our ThinkingSphinx indexes a table with over 500 million records. We are trying to find 120,000 records that match a given query. However, I don't want to change the `max_matches` for fear that we will run out of RAM.

Obviously, the error we are getting is:

```
Exception ThinkingSphinx::SphinxError -> offset out of bounds (offset=100000, max_matches=100000)

<query>
AND `sphinx_deleted` = 0 LIMIT 100000, 1000 OPTION max_matches=100000;
```

Is there a way to either:

1. Dynamically change the `max_matches` if I have not aggregated enough results?
2. A better solution that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Well you can just set it **just** as big as you need. ie set max_matches to offset+limit.

ie to `LIMIT 100000, 1000 OPTION max_matches=101000`  or `LIMIT 7000, 1000 OPTION max_matches=8000`

Answer (score 0):

You're perhaps aware of this already, but just in case: the `max_matches` setting in `config/thinking_sphinx.yml` is the absolute maximum. However, you can pass in `:max_matches` to any search query to limit the maximum results for that search request.

So, could you set `max_matches` in `config/thinking_sphinx.yml` to 120,000, and then make sure you're enforcing a lower value for most searches except this particular one?